# Camera matrix from essential matrix

Tags: camera, computer-vision, camera-calibration, extrinsic-parameters

I am trying to extract camera matrix from essential matrix. I found some answers about this.

[determine camera rotation and translation matrix from essential matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778417/determine-camera-rotation-and-translation-matrix-from-essential-matrix)

[Rotation and Translation from Essential Matrix incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161002/rotation-and-translation-from-essential-matrix-incorrect)

In these answers, they suggest me to use `newE` where `[U,S,V] = svd(E)` and `newE = U*diag(1,1,0)*Vt`. I don't understand why I need to use `newE`. As I know, singular values are unique. So changing singular values to `diag(1,1,0)` seems to make `E` to completely different values.

I read 'Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision' also, but it just refers to the ideal case, i.e., singular values are (1,1,0). I didn't find the reason of using `newE`.

Please can anyone explain me why people use `newE`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then since you source data (and thus `E`) is usually noisy real world data, then by using `diag(1,1,0)` you are constraining the matrix to be of the correct scale and rank and algebraically enforcing the geometric constraints.

Wikipedia also a [has a nice section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_matrix#Determining_R_and_t_from_E) explaining this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In that way, constraints can be satisfied, but the result seems to become incorrect. Is the result pretty reliable?